# Regex to ignore naming pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, jshint

We're starting to blend TypeScript with regular Javascript. We have JSHint working in our build process. I need to find a way for JSHint to ignore the typescript files that are currently being used.

The option in JSHint is currently `src: '<%= pkg.webapp %>/**/*.js',`

I don't see an option to ignore specific file types in jshint.

I have it working by adding

```
/* jshint ignore:start */
/* jshint ignore:end */
```

to each of the TypeScript files, but I'd rather it be automated.

Can someone help me with a regex that includes the vairable `<%= pkg.webapp %>` at the beginning?

**I need to ignore files that end in `_ts.js`**

Comment: Maybe .jshintrc file with setting

Comment: Take a look [.jshintignore](http://jshint.com/docs/cli/#ignoring-files). This might be what you need. You basically just need to create a `.jshintignore` file in your root directory and add path patterns to exclude files from being linted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know `_ts.js` will be the literal string, with no variation:

```
/(_ts.js)$/g
```

You don't need a var to anticipate filename, just match against the end of string. Use this website to rapidly test regex: http://regexr.com/

`()` is a substring, `$` denotes "ends in."

which you would use like so:

```
var regex =     /(_ts.js)$/g;
regex.test(someString);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the [ignores](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint#ignores) option. It accepts an array

```
module.exports = {
    src: '<%= pkg.webapp %>/**/*.js',
    options: {
        ignores: ['<%= pkg.webapp %>/**/*_ts.js'],
    }
}
```